# iOS App crash on start when debugging WatchKit Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I am developing an iOS app and its watch kit extension and trying to run them on the simulator with Xcode 6.4.

Both of them run fine on real devices, but unfortunately I don't own the AppleWatch I use for testing so I have to test the extension on the simulator.

If I run the app alone it's all ok, but when I run the extension and tap on the app on the iPhone simulator, it crashes immediately and I can't figure out why.

```
Sep 12 11:52:44 MacBook-Pro-** assertiond[22563]: assertion failed: 14F27 12H141: assertiond + 12334 [EDAF3958-87C7-3C61-A8E6-24689FBBE168]: 0x1
Sep 12 11:52:44 MacBook-Pro-**.local SpringBoard[29507]: LICreateIconForImage passed NULL CGImageRef image
Sep 12 11:52:45 MacBook-Pro-** com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.0868CE09-5C9E-4445-A8C9-48F00AA445AF.launchd_sim[22544] (UIKitApplication:**myAppBundleId**[0xb354][29533]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Everything used to work some days ago, so I must have done something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Still I don't know what was the reason that caused this behavior, but I resolved  by using this tool: https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate

I removed any trace of cocoapods from the project and then reinstalled all the pods again.

After that everything went back to normal.